# what are the server requirements to host an asp.net mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Hai guys, 
        Any one knows what are the server requirements to host an asp.net mvc application....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[From MSDN](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=53289097-73ce-43bf-b6a6-35e00103cb4b&displaylang=en#Requirements):

**Operating Systems**:  Windows Server 2003; Windows Server 2008; Windows Vista; Windows XP

**.NET version**: [.NET Framework SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=AB99342F-5D1A-413D-8319-81DA479AB0D7&displaylang=en)